# Stored procedure returns no columns

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I have the following stored procedure :

```
 SET ANSI_NULLS ON
 GO
 SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
 GO
 ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SearchMediaTitles] 

   @query varchar(50),
   @limit int = 6,
   @userId int
 AS
 SET FMTONLY OFF
 BEGIN

 declare @searchString varchar(52)

 set @searchString = '"' + @query +'*"'
 IF @userId!=NULL
 SELECT TOP (@limit) ID, Title from Media where CONTAINS([Title], @searchString)
 AND ID IN
  (
  SELECT FavoriteMedia_ID
  FROM dbo.UserMedia
  WHERE UserMedia_Media_ID=@userId
  )
 ELSE
 SELECT TOP (@limit) ID, Title from Media where CONTAINS([Title], @searchString)

 END
```

In Entity Framework when I try to map it at function import for a complex type it says

> *the selected stored procedure returns no columns*

I've read about this on the internet and I found out I need to set `SET FMTONLY OFF`, but as you can see it didn't work.

Any ideas?

**EDIT**:

I've changed `SELECT` to `*` and it return an empty result. I think it's related to problem described above

Comment: Bit of a bodge but what if you just temporarily change the definition to `SELECT ID, Title from Media` so it is a simple straight forward proc with no conditional logic then do the entity framework mapping then put your original code back as both paths look like they will return a resultset of that shape.

Comment: I tried this, but it doesn't work

Comment: Did you get rid of the `SET FMTONLY` statement? Also is this something specific to that stored proc or do you get this for all stored procedures?

Comment: Yes. I tried to use that because of this problem. I've read on the internet about it, but I couldn't resolve it

Comment: And you definitely changed the definition to exactly `SELECT ID, Title from Media` you didn't leave `TOP(@limit)` in there? According to [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/e7f598a2-6827-4b27-a09d-aefe733b48e6/) that might mess things up as EF will pass `NULL` for all parameters. And that will cause an error for `TOP`

Comment: have you tried the sp works on sql management studio?

Comment: @MartinSmith Yes, I tried without limit too.      For Mert: How ?

Comment: I might be wrong, but shouldn't SET FMTONLY OFF be after the BEGIN?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For everyone who has the same problem, this is what I've done.

First I modified the stored procedure to a simple one like this :

```
  SELECT  [column1],[column2] FROM [table]
```

I imported it in `Entity Framework`, created the complex type and mapping properties

Then I changed it back and updated the model and now it works.
I think `Entity Framework` has some problems with complex stored procedures. From what I read it can't get results for dynamic stored procedures or for a stored procedure which use `temp tables`.

PS: When I call it with Ajax, I call it using  `data.column1 and data.column2`. If I use `data.value' it returns`undefined` .

It's kinda weird.

**EDIT:** It's like Martin said but I don't know why it didn't worked in the first place ! Thank you btw !

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are missing the single quotes on your prefix_term. 
So this:

```
set @searchString = '"' + @query +'*"'
```

Should be:

```
set @searchString = CHAR(39) + '"' + @query +'*"' + CHAR(39)
```